# Redirecting multiple subdomains to specific folder under one site with IIS 8

Tags: iis, binding, url-rewriting, subdomain

So basically here's what I'm trying to do. We have a domain "abc.com" that is hosted elsewhere by an unrelated company. We have an internal web server that we're trying to have host multiple websites through subdomains under a single IIS site. For example:

```
Server
 Sites
  Default Web Site (The direct IP would lead to here but that's it)
   > Site1 (site1.abc.com)
   > Site2 (site2.abc.com)
   > Site3 (site3.abc.com)
```

Unfortunately the structure of the site was made this way by the people who installed the application and it can't be moved so adding and moving sites really isn't an option for me. I know how to bind the default site to an IP address and do the host headers but I'm not sure how to make the site have those subdomains go to the proper folders. I've read that URL rewriting may be the option but I'm a little puzzled by it and it can't be site1.abc.com/Site1 which is what I'm worried URL rewrite would do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Url rewrite rule would have to match everything and then have a condition on the hostname, like this:

```
<rules>
     <rule name="site1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site1.abc.com" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="/site1/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
     <rule name="site2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="site2.abc.com" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="/site2/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
</rules>
```

These rules would get the content of the request for site1.abc.com from abc.com/site1, but the user would still just see site1.abc.com